# Alterar um body inteiro do Scaffold

Tags: flutter, dart

Olá!

Estou tentando finalizar um app, mas parei em um problema.

Tenho uma tela com um `Scaffold` e um `action` no appBar com widget que retorna a data.

Gostaria de saber como atualizar um texto com a data dentro do body. Sei que ele pode ser atualizado. Pois, consigo dar um print e ver que altera o valor mas, não consigo alterar o texto.

arquivo data.dart

```
class Data extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DataState createState() => _DataState();
}

class _DataState extends State<Data> {
  StoreChamada testeData = StoreChamada();
  DateTime selectDate = DateTime.now();

  Future<Null> _selectdate(BuildContext context) async {

    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2000, 1),
        lastDate: DateTime(2050));
    testeData.setData(DateFormat('dd-MM').format(picked));
    if (picked != null && picked != selectDate)
      setState(() {

        selectDate = picked;

      });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var data = DateFormat('dd-MM').format(selectDate);
    return Row(children: <Widget>[
      Text(data + '  '),
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(IconData(59670, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _selectdate(context);
          });
        },
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

função que chamo para atualizar valor da variável sdata com a data que uso no body.

```
void setData(value) => sdata = value;
```

tela da lista que tem o texto.

```
 body: Container(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(sdata == null
              ? '${DateFormat('dd-MM').format(DateTime.now())}'
              : sdata),
```

Tentei varias coisas, pensei em usar um setstate(){} no body mas nem sei se isso seria possível. Enfim, se alguem puder ajudar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a tela que gostaria de alterar.
Tenho um widget com texto e data que são atualizados assim que alteroa a data, mas não consigo atualizar a parte amarela que é onde ficam os dados que atualizo dependendo da data. O valor da data é alterado mas a tela não atualiza, somente quando dou hotreload.

Comment: Não ficou claro qual é o problema, você precisa atualizar qual scaffold? Qual é a estrutura dos widgets?  Se você está instanciando o seu widget, você não pode usar uma callback?

Comment: O que tem o texto sdata, o último trecho do código.

Comment: Ok, como os seus widgets estão estruturados?  Você tem um Widget com um scaffold, e dentro deste você tem  o seu Widget para selecionar a data?

Comment: Isso. Tenho uma tela com um scaffold -> appBar(action-> widget que muda a data, o primeiro trecho do código.

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se entendi bem o seu problema, mas se você precisa passar algum dado de um Widget filho para um padre, existem diferentes modos para fazer isso, mas o mais simples é simplesmente passar uma função para o Widget filho que será chamada a cada vez que você quiser executar algum código, algo tipo:

O seu Widget filho recebe a função como parametro do construtor e irá chamar ela a cada evento:

```
class SelectDate extends StatelessWidget {
  SelectDate({Key key, this.onChange}) : super(key: key);
  
  final Function(DateTime) onChange;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
        onPressed: () {
          onChange?.call(DateTime.now());
        },
      );
  }
}
```

E então no seu Widget pai, no casso dentro ao seu Scaffold, quando você cria o seu Widget filho:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        SelecteDate(
          onChange: (data) {
            /// Faça algo com a nova data
          }
        )
      ]
    ),
  ),
);
```

Se este era o seu problema, ele pode ser resolvido assim, de qualquer maneira eu vi que você está fazendo uso não necessário do método `setState`, eu sugiro você dar uma olhada na [documentação](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) sobre o que estes métodos fazem e como usá-los ao seu favor. Existem também diversos tutoriais no canal do Flutter no youtube, um dos que podem ser interessantes para o seu caso é o [InheritedWidget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1t-8rBCGBYw). E também `Future<Null>` onde `Null` não é um tipo válido, se você não tem nada para retornar desta função o correto é `Future<void>`

Comment: Cara muito obrigado pela resposta, não consigo testar agora mas assim que der eu testo.

Comment: Se não resolver, explica melhor o seu problema que eu vejo como posso ajudar

Comment: Cara, na verdade eu coloquei o setstate pois estava tentando de tudo rsrs. eu tenho um widget que é a data e ele desenha im iconbutton e um texto com  a data. Coloco esse widget no action do appBar. quando altero a data eu até consigo alterar a data do text desse widget e a variáve sdata só que eu precisava redesenhar a tela para trazer as informações do firestrore, quando troco a data e doou hotreload ele funciona rsrs.

Comment: Pelo que vi da sua imagem, o código que coloquei de exemplo pode ser aplicado sem nenhum problema.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado mesmo, vou tentar usar a sua solução, mas estou pensando em dar uma estudada em modular acho que vai me ajudar muito, inclusive nessa solução.